# How to access all files that end with ".mp3" extension in the internal storage of my phone using Android Studio?

Tags: android

I am trying to access audio files in my phone from my application. 
I am relatively new to Android Programming. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you searched for this? Plenty of questions regarding accessing files on the internal storage. Show us some effort first

Comment: You should search before asking, here is one [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323438/how-to-find-mp3-files-from-sdcard-in-android-programatically).

Comment: Query the `MediaStore` for media with the MP3 MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
String path="/sdcard/";    /* assuming u wanted to start from your sdcard */

private void updatePlaylist(){
    File home=new File(path);
    if (home.listFiles(new MP3filter()).length>0){
        for (File file: home.listFiles(new MP3filter())){
            alist.add(file.getName());
        }
    }
    if (alist.size()==0){
        tv.setText("No music files");
    }
    else
    tv.setText(alist.get(0).toString());


}
class MP3filter implements FilenameFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return (filename.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }
}
```

Comment: So you think you do not have to do this recursive?

Comment: please elaborate @greenapps

Comment: Dont you think OP wants all mp3 files? So also those from /sdcard/Music and /sdcard/mp3s ? And so on? Of all subdirectories? You know the concept of recursive? Unclear if you do.

Comment: i know the concept of recursive and i've got your point. i just posted this for starters. i actually appreciate it if you can suggest an edit @greenapps